# There are/were far too many things which happened before

Tags: sentence-construction

> **There were** far too many things which happened before.
>
> **There are** far too many things which happened before.

Could you tell me, please, those sentences sound natural?

Is it possible to use "there are" in that context if it happened in the past? Why? *[I have seen both versions on the internet.]*

Comment: Well...I'd use "There were too many things that **had happened** before." Past perfect is helpful here because you're talking about two different events in time. I'd also use **that** because you're not comparing things. (Yes, I know some people will disagree here.)

Comment: I would just say "Too many things happened before."  Unless you are getting paid by the word. :^)